# Query performance tuning of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables:

```
SELECT [DealerdistributionId]
      ,[DealerCode]
      ,[BarCode]
      ,[BarCode2]
      ,[Model]
      ,[DONumber]
      ,[DistributionDate]
  FROM [tblDealerDistributionDetails]
```

yields these results

[image]

and another table:

```
SELECT [ProductRegID]
      ,[ProductType]
      ,[ProductModelID]
      ,[SalerID]
      ,[ProductID]
      ,[PhoneNumber]
      ,[RegistrationDate]
  FROM [tblProductRegistration]
```

results

[image]

The second table `tblProductRegistration` logs `ProductID` from `BarCode` or `BarCode2` from the first table `tblDealerDistributionDetails`, but only one `BarCode` or `BarCode2`.

I want to find which Dealer has what quantity of model with entry in tblProductRegistration.

Output:
DelarCode,Model,TotalEntry in tblProductRegistration.

I have tried this

```
select DealerCode, COUNT(*) as [Activated]
 from  tblDealerDistributionDetails 
 where   
 ( BarCode in (select ProductID from tblProductRegistration where RegistrationDate >='2016-03-01' and RegistrationDate <='2016-03-02') 
 or 
 BarCode2 in (select ProductID from tblProductRegistration where RegistrationDate >='2016-03-01' and RegistrationDate <='2016-03-02') ) 
 and Model= 'Olvio L12' group by DealerCode
```

for a specific model 'Olvio L12' but it causes perfomance issue.I need faster query perfomance

with faster query performance.Please help.

Comment: Are you asking us to write a join query? What have you tried? How did it go, result-wise and performance-wise?

Comment: Yeah. except obviously making us write your code as you are unwilling to even try something. May I suggest going to a site where you can hire someone to do your job for you? We are not a coding service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you show nor attempt nor willingness to solve the problem yourself, taking stackoverflow.com for a free coding service.

Comment: Sorry for late edit.I have tried this but in causes performance issue.so i want to improve performance other than in Query

Comment: Indeed you need to design tables and indices for performance, then have a query that uses this design to gain the benefits. I only recently gave [a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35711251/243373) to a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35709994/243373). Maybe not 100% similar, but see what you can pick from the answer.

Comment: @TT Helpful indeed. I going for SQL SERVER execution plan  for finding permanence of Query by myself .any suggestion appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_p
    ON tblProductRegistration (RegistrationDate, ProductID)
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_d
    ON tblDealerDistributionDetails (model, DealerCode) INCLUDE (BarCode, BarCode2)
GO

SELECT DealerCode, COUNT_BIG(*) AS [Activated]
FROM tblDealerDistributionDetails d
WHERE model = 'Olvio L12'
    AND EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM tblProductRegistration r
        WHERE r.RegistrationDate BETWEEN '20160301' AND '20160302'
            AND r.ProductID IN (d.BarCode, d.BarCode2)
    )
GROUP BY DealerCode
--OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```